# Are there performance benchmarks of VTD-XML comparing java C++ C# and C versions of VTD-XML?

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

[VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) is available in C++ C, Java and C#. I am looking performance benchmarks that compares all these language version processing fairly complex XML docs.